# Clicking brakes after wheel bearing replacement

Tags: brakes, chevrolet, noise, cobalt

I have a 2006 Chevrolet Cobalt SS.

I just did a wheel bearing/ hub replacement on the front passenger wheel because the old one was shot but now I have a new problem. There is a clicking sound whenever I am driving but as soon as I hit the brakes it stops. It's very loud from inside the car and in the outside you can hear it as well. When I turn to the right it gets noticeably louder.

Another thing I noticed was that my brakes are a lot weaker than they were before I did the replacement. I have had clicking brakes before but only when I am coming to a stop. I'm no mechanic but I know what I'm doing for the most part but this has got me stumped and everyone I know has never came across this problem.

Comment: @ArtursBolsunovskis  You should make your comment into an answer!

Answer (score 1):

if it is since you have replaced a hub and bearings, on the same wheel, then all you can do is to get the wheel off and look for a reason. Maybe a new hub wheel studs touches something. Looking now for your hub in Google, and looks like it might be the bolt that holds the hub (3 bolts, red arrow) touching one of a wheel stud (green arrow). Or just any other similar issue, sometimes a brake caliper touches something because it is a moving part, you can never know....

[image]